# A2Lix Translation Form in Sublime3

Tags: symfony, doctrine-extensions, a2lix-translation

I am developing a multilanguage site in Symfony3 with KnpDoctrineExtension and a2lix/translation-form-bundle.

I followed the documentation both for KNP and A2Lix: controller and entities are OK but when I try to build and render the form I get a 500 error

```
Could not load type "a2lix_translations"
```

All the examples I found are from projects in Symfony2 so I am wondering if this is an issue related to the version I am using.

I loaded the bundle in app\AppKernel.php

```
new Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Bundle\DoctrineBehaviorsBundle(),
new A2lix\TranslationFormBundle\A2lixTranslationFormBundle(),
```

and I added the following lines in app\config\config.yml

```
a2lix_translation_form:
    locale_provider: default
    locales: [br, it, ru]
    default_locale: en
    required_locales: [br, it]
    manager_registry: doctrine
    templating: "A2lixTranslationFormBundle::default.html.twig"
```

Thank you for your attention and for your help.

Comment: Can please someone just confirm that the a2lix form bundle work with Symfony3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm that the stable version 2.* works fine with KNP doctrine behaviors bundle and Symfony 3.1.

Check [demo](https://github.com/a2lix/Demo) provided by the author of the form bundle.

Answer (score 0):

in sf3 you have to add :

```
use A2lix\TranslationFormBundle\Form\Type\TranslationsType;
```

and then use this:

```
$builder->add('translations', TranslationsType::class);
```

instead of :

```
$builder->add('translations', 'a2lix_translations');
```